# Is there a 3rd PDF creation tool that has reasonable feature partity with Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'd like to buy a "full" PDF creator product (not a converter) that perhaps has 80% of the features of Acrobat but are less expensive.

Do any products like this exist?

Comment: I wish you had been more specific about what features you were looking for. Nearly everything that needs doing with PDFs can be done with free, open source, tools, just not everything with the same thing. Ghostscript and pdflatex are the most powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used Adobe, then we went to Nitro, and after that, we settled on [Bluebeam](http://www.bluebeam.com).  Bluebeam is pretty sweet.  For our needs, it was a much better fit than Nitro, and has some features (like its stapler) that is just awesome, and really easy to use.  They have very good support as well.  We actually had a very big analysis of several vendors, since we were ordering 1500 licenses at work.  The Sharepoint integration is very nice, if you need it.  As well as their free demo :)

Edit: both Nitro and Bluebeam have free trials, give them both a shot, and see which one you like.  There is also CutePDF, which is free, but not nearly as complete, or customizable.  Digitally signing documents was a HUGE feature we needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try Nitro: http://www.nitropdf.com/products.htm
I use it and like it a lot more than Acrobat.